Не активируется Win 11
Слетела активация win 11 после того, как сбились региональные настройки.
У меня две ОС: linux, win 11. ОС стоят на разных дисках. Иногда после линукса заходишь в винду и в ней отстают часы, регион меняется. Всегда все было нормально - синхронизируешь время и регион и все нормально, но сегодня активация винды слетела и переактивировать ее не получается.
У меня Windows 11 pro цифровая лицензия, привязанная к учетной записи. Лицензия бессрочная
Пробовал на другом ПК и там все активируется нормально, когда входишь в учетку - активация подтягивается сама.
Коды ошибок всегда разные, то аппратное обеспечение изменилось, то не может подключиться к серверам microsoft. Ошибки меняются, в зависимости от того, введу я ключ вручную или нет.
Что я попробовал и это все не помогло:

Переустановил win 11
Перепрошивал биос на разные версии
Менял учетки
Проверял эту цифровую лицензию на другом ПК (на другом работает нормально)
В личном кабинете майкрософта удалял все привязанные устройства
Удалял ключ из системы и реестра
Ставил бесплатный ключ от майкрософта, после его сбрасывал и снова пытался активировать свой





и что конкретно делается наоборот?
обычно, когда у вас лицензия привязана к учетной записи - никаких проблем не возникает. По крайней мере, эти проблемы, зачастую, решаются перепривязкой лицензии к текущему ПК. У меня  4 ПК между которыми я перекидываю свою учетку, когда мне это необходимо. И всегда все нормально переактивируется. Мне не понятно, почему сейчас эта цифровая лицензия не активируется на одном из этих 4 ПК. Если бы она не была привязана к учетке, то непонимания не было бы.

Совет ещё нужен? Использовать локальную учётную запись и активировать с помощью MAS 2.7. Вот что наоборот. То есть всё.

Для меня полностью остаётся загадкой, как установки в одной ОС влияют на установки в другой. Если слетает время, это уже проблема, возможно, аппаратная. Такое видел - в стационарных компах попадались старые батарейки. Но регион... Первое, что делает Винда на старте - проверяет время. От этого зависит всё - обновления, местоположение и т.д. Кроме того, в Винде в настройках есть автосинхронизация времени "с неким сервером". Она вообще включена по умолчанию.

Так mas делает не то, что нужно. Я он просто генерит ключ и активирует. Я хотел, чтобы конкретно моя лицензия была, которую я покупал и которая была привязан к моему аккаунту

Хотя сейчас, заменив ключ на свой, активация осталась. Ключ в системе и реестре так же изменился

«постоянно на 3 часа назад» — очевидно, причина в том, что винда хранит локальное время, а линукс хранит UTC, и из-за этого несовпадения они постоянно меняют время друг после друга

Все верно выше написал andreymal.
Перевел винду на utc и проверил. Все ок.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
